# How to install canon ip1980 printer to ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, printing, canon

I try to install my printer canon ip1980. But it failed. It didn't recognize my printer. Hope you can help me with this.

Comment: There is a linux driver [here](http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/printers/InkJet/PIXMA_iP_series/PIXMA_iP1900.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to add this repository

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk
   ```
2. Then get your synaptic and search `cnijfilter`
3. back to your Printer Setting → Add printer → Enter URI
4. Type this

   ```
   cnijusb:/dev/usb/lp0
   ```